# Popup blocker disables onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a button that is connected a JS function to operate SSO for another website. The button works when popup blocker is disabled, however it no longer works when popup block is turned on. How do I get `onClick` to work while the popup blocker is activated? Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" value="Launch AdEase" onClick="postURL()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function postURL() {
  var idOfClientFirm = document.getElementById('mfID').value;
  document.getElementById('<%= txtField2.ClientID%>').value = idOfClientFirm;

  document.getElementById('<%= loginLinkButton.ClientID%>').click(); 
}
```

Comment: Does the login link pop up a window?

Comment: @BenM It pops up a new tab.